# Adobe Edge: change element's width at document.compositionReady and at window.resize

Tags: css, adobe-edge

In my Adobe Edge project, I'm trying to create a website that adapts according to the width of the window. So my plan is:
1. Check the width when the site is loaded and adapt the elements if necessary.
2. Check the width whenever the window is resized and adapt the elements if necessary.

In order to do this I've created this function.

```
function adapt() {
    if ($( window ).width() <= 800) {
        sym.$("testo_box").css("width", "99%");     
        sym.getComposition().getStage().$("corpus_txt").html("Test");
    }
}
```

You can see what the elements are in the attached image.
[Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onCq6.jpg)

**The first problem** is I couldn't find any way to create this function in such a place and in such a way that it can be global, and call-able from within other scripts.

But **my main problem** is this: when I place this function inside *Stage -> window.resize*, and call it with:

```
adapt();
```

It works perfectly. But when I place it inside *Stage -> document.compositionReady* and call it the same way, the following line:

```
sym.$("testo_box").css("width", "99%");
```

doesn't produce the expected result. It does nothing.
I'm sure the *if* condition is checked and verified, because the other line:

```
sym.getComposition().getStage().$("corpus_txt").html("Test");
```

produces the expected result.

I have a workaround for this, which makes use of the timeline and labels, but quite frankly is very impractical.

Just to clear things, up, I know it's pointless to create that function to call it right below from the same "place" and only once. The result would be identical if just the "if" part was there. The plan is to make the function global and just call it from those "places".

Thanks to everyone who will be so kind to help out a newbie like me, and hopefully the answers will help other people as well.